# Ito-Stratonovich drift term for spatial white noise

Tags: statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes, noise, brownian-motion, fluctuation-dissipation

Suppose I have a Langevin equation with multiplicative noise of the form

$$ \dot{x} = f(x) + g(x)\eta(t)  $$

where $ \eta(t) $ is a Gaussian white noise with zero average, unit strength, and delta correlated in time i.e. $$\langle \eta(t)\eta(t') \rangle = \delta(t-t').$$ The standard physics-focused references for SDEs (van Kampen, Jacobs) show that one can convert between Ito and Stratonovich interpretations by adding or subtracting the drift term $ \frac{1}{2}g(x)g'(x) $.

However, in many dissipative dynamics and/or fluctuating hydrodynamics theories, noise will be delta correlated in both time and space, i.e. $$\langle \eta(\mathbf{r},t)\eta(\mathbf{r}',t') \rangle = \delta(t-t')\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'). $$

How does one find the drift term to convert between Ito and Stratonovich conventions in this case? It seems clear from dimensional analysis that the old prescription for the drift term will no longer hold.

Comment: Since you haven't gotten any answers in the week since you've posted, you may want to try your luck over at [math.se] or perhaps [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/).

Comment: I have no idea, but you could try to write the "Fokker-Planck" equation associated with your partial stochastic differential equation. Then you can proceed as in the classical texts you mention and see which term you have to add so that an Itô and a Stratonovich equation have the same Fokker-Planck description.